# Relative speed between two photons

Tags: special-relativity, photons, speed-of-light

Is it possible to fix an inertial frame to a photon moving in vacuum?
If yes, what is the speed of another photon moving in vacuum with respect to this frame?
What is the proper time measured by the second photon between two events?
Please provide references for the answers.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/724431/frame-of-reference-of-a-photon) and probably many others.

Comment: @Ghoster Oops. Should i delete my question? I am relatively new here.

Comment: No, because it has an answer. But next time, you can use the search box to see whether similar questions have already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to fix an inertial frame to a photon moving in vacuum?

No. In an inertial frame a photon moves at $c$, and in a frame attached to a photon it moves at $0$. That is a contradiction, so it is not possible.